# XML writer with custom formatting

Tags: c#, xml, formatting

I need to create a human-readable XML file. XmlWriter seems to be almost perfect for this, but I'd like to insert line breaks or, in general, custom whitespace where I want them. Neither [WriteRaw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/0755ytay.aspx) nor [WriteWhitespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.writewhitespace.aspx) seem to work between the attributes in an element. The latter looks like it should work (*This method is used to manually format your document*), but throws `InvalidOperationException` (*Token StartAttribute in state Element Content would result in an invalid XML document*) if used in place of the comments below.

Is there a workaround for XmlWriter or a third-party XML library that supports this?

Example code (LINQPad-statements ready):

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
var settings = new XmlWriterSettings {
    OmitXmlDeclaration = true,
    Indent = true,
    IndentChars = "  ",
};
using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(sb, settings)) {
    writer.WriteStartElement("X");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("A", "1");
    // write line break
    writer.WriteAttributeString("B", "2");
    // write line break
    writer.WriteAttributeString("C", "3");
    writer.WriteEndElement();
}
Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Actual result:

```
<X A="1" B="2" C="3" />
```

Desired result (B and C may be not aligned with A - that's fine, /> can be left on the line with C):

```
<X A="1"
   B="2"
   C="3"
/>
```

Comment: `human-readable XML file`: smells like spec creep!

Comment: @Rawling, forgot to mention - I don't want them all on new lines, just where it makes sense in the context (i.e. only add manually)

Comment: Oh I see your point! (Just not in time to avoid turning my comment into an answer...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You still has the background StringBuilder - use it. :

```
  var sb = new StringBuilder();
  var settings = new XmlWriterSettings {
    OmitXmlDeclaration = true,
    Indent = true,
    IndentChars = "  ",
  };
  using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(sb, settings)) {
    writer.WriteStartElement("X");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("A", "1");
    writer.Flush();
    sb.Append("\r\n");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("B", "2");
    writer.Flush();
    sb.Append("\r\n");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("C", "3");
    writer.WriteEndElement();
  }
  Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Comment: Ah yes, haven't thought of that for some reason. Thank you!